# Change rotation of camera in angular

Tags: angular, aframe

I am using Aframe in angular and trying to Change rotation of camera. When the video starts playing, it will start out showing us 180 degrees on the 0,0, coordinate

Here is my code:
[image]

```html
<a-camera reverse-mouse-drag="true" rotation-reader wasd-controls-enabled="false">
  <a-entity cursor position="0 0 -1" geometry="primitive: shpere; radius: 0.005" material="color:#000000; shader: flat; opacity: 0.6">
  </a-entity>
</a-camera>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Cheat?

Wrap it in a div and use CSS to rotate it.

```
<div [style.transform]="'rotate({{rotateDeg}}deg)'">
    <a-camera></a-camera>
</div>
```